# How to get azure cli access token programatically?

Tags: .net, azure

I have to query azure to get vmss in a resource group equivalent to below az cli command:

```sh
az vmss list --resource-group <resource-group>  -o json
```

Internally this calls below rest-api:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets?api-version=2020-12-01
```

I need to get above information programatically in c-sharp. Using rest API client need jwt token to call above API. Going by documentation, below is URL to get jwt:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={clientId} ...
```

I could get above URl from az login command. However, this is an interactive command which requires user to enter login Id, password and have a redirect_url to a api running in localhost which receives the token.

Is there any API that returns auth token as json?

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Really clean answer. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you could simply use the [`VisualStudioCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.visualstudiocredential?view=azure-dotnet) of [`Azure.Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity?view=azure-dotnet) to auth and get the token, NuGet [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity/).

The `VisualStudioCredential` uses the user account logged in the VS to auth directly, refer to the sample below, the `accessToken` is the token you want to call the REST API.

**Sample:**

```
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TokenCredential tokenCredential = new VisualStudioCredential();
            TokenRequestContext requestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new string[] { "https://management.azure.com" });
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var accessToken = tokenCredential.GetToken(requestContext, cts.Token).Token;

        }
            
    }
}
```

**Note:** In this sample, you could also change `VisualStudioCredential` to other credentials, e.g. [`ClientSecretCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential?view=azure-dotnet), [`DefaultAzureCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet), [`ManagedIdentityCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.managedidentitycredential?view=azure-dotnet), etc, details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity?view=azure-dotnet), you could choose them depend on your requirements.

---

**Besides**, actually it is no need to call the REST API manually in your case, you could use the .net SDK [`Azure.ResourceManager.Compute`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.Compute/) directly, use the [`VirtualMachineScaleSetsOperations.List(String, CancellationToken) Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.compute.virtualmachinescalesetsoperations.list?view=azure-dotnet-preview#Azure_ResourceManager_Compute_VirtualMachineScaleSetsOperations_List_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) to list all VM scale sets under a resource group, the `vmssList` below is what you want.

**Sample:**

```
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute;
using System.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var subscriptionid = "<your-subscription-id>";
            var rgname = "<group-name>";
            TokenCredential tokenCredential = new VisualStudioCredential();
            ComputeManagementClient client = new ComputeManagementClient(subscriptionid, tokenCredential);
            var vmssList = client.VirtualMachineScaleSets.List(rgname).ToList();
      
        }
    
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use service principal credentials instead of user credentials. Make sure that service principal has access to required resources to perform any action using generated token.

You can get the access token via `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/token` REST API.

You can check [here](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7BTenantID%7D%7D/oauth2/token) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a user context, you should use **managed identity** for authentication. Managed identity is a *managed* service principal.

Depending on where you run your workload, you have several options to obtain a token:

- [How to use managed identities for App Service and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?context=%2Fazure%2Factive-directory%2Fmanaged-identities-azure-resources%2Fcontext%2Fmsi-context&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)
- [How to use managed identities for Azure resources on an Azure VM to acquire an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)